Element not found in Selenium using Java
In the below code ion-modal is not displaying in the screen when ion-fab-button in the ion-fab-list is clicked. Even ion-fab-list is not displayed when fab button is clicked.
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement fabButton = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//ion-footer//ion-fab//ion-fab-button"));
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fabButton);
Thread.sleep(3000);

if (fabButton.isEnabled()) {
    WebElement referOption = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//ion-footer//ion-fab//ion-fab-list//ion-fab-button[1]"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", referOption);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", referOption);
    System.out.println("fabButton is enabled, clicking referOption[1]");
    Thread.sleep(1000);  // Wait for the action to complete
    this.referUsingVehicleNumber();
}

Below is the HTML.
<ion-modal [isOpen]="vehicleNumberInputModalFlag" style="max-width: 96%; max-height: 50%; margin-block: auto; margin-inline: auto; border-radius: 12px;">
    <ng-template>
        <ion-card class="form-card">
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-end">
                    <ion-icon name="close" (click)="cancel()" class="ion-padding-end" style="margin-top:1%"></ion-icon>
                </ion-row>
                <br>
                <ion-item fill="outline">
                    <ion-label position="floating" class="input-label" style="background: var(--ion-card-background);" translatekey="VEHICLE_NUMBER" update-translation="false"> Vehicle Number </ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                <br>
                <ion-item fill="outline">
                    <ion-select [lang]="selectedLanguage" #operator="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedOperator" name="referredBy" class="select-input" label="Referred By" labelPlacement="floating" interface="popover" (ionChange)="onOperatorSelected($event)" translatekey="REFERRED_BY" update-translation="false" required="">
                        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let operator of operators" [value]="operator">{{operator.firstName}} {{operator.middleName}} {{operator.lastName}}</ion-select-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
                <div class="alert-buttons">
                    <ion-button name="refer" [lang]="selectedLanguage" (click)="saveReferral(vehicleNumber)" [disabled]="vehicleNo.invalid || operator.invalid" translatekey="REFER" update-translation="false">Refer</ion-button>
                </div>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ng-template>
</ion-modal>

I tried using Thread.sleep() instead of wait and tried changing element locator. When Thread.sleep() is used, its showing NoSuchElementException, indicating ion-fab-button is not found.

have you tried switchto active element?

Yes, I have tried with switchTo.activeElement. I am getting error like, unable to locate the element ion-fab-button.

I'm not sure how we're supposed to help you. That's not HTML, that's pre-rendered mobile code... and the code you've included doesn't include the part that your locators are looking for. So either your locators ARE bad or you've included the wrong bit of mobile code. We actually need the rendered code... you'll need to use the inspector to get that for us (and probably yourself if you're looking at this and trying to write locators).

This is the element which I want to locate













